# How to change the zoom on an embedded google mymap?

Tags: google-maps

I embedded a google mymap in my website using the embed code they provide. However it is zoomed much too far out. How can I zoom it in?

I added the second character (undrscore) so it would display.
<_iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&source=embed&msa=0&msid=212526618623367333770.0004a2dd56ade1cf3f7eb&ll=34.931542,-81.894879&spn=0.043299,0.140592&output=embed">
View Map Name in a larger map

Comment: Just add the '&z=6' to the end of the url after 'output=embed' and it works fine for me. The ampersand is a separator character for embedding GET variables, read about it at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Comment: @Mapperz - Thanks, your method of z's worked on one map. However the following map doesn't have zs:

reply you can add &z=xx to the end of any google maps embedded map for zoom level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the zoom manually

add **&z=4** (from 1 to 17 map and 1 to 22 for satellite)

example:

http://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=208023577543881741272.00000111d236e89e8ed37&ll=50.233152,-127.880859&spn=34.8595,79.013672&z=4

and zoomed in more

**&z=6**

http://maps.google.ca/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=208023577543881741272.00000111d236e89e8ed37&ll=50.233152,-127.880859&spn=34.8595,79.013672&z=6